# TypeError with JSON data in ionic2

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, ionic2

i have a question on how to avoid errors in typescript, when filtering a particular variable in JSON data.
part of my JSON data will look like:

> With contents of multimedia:

```
"per_facet": [],
"geo_facet": [],
"multimedia": [
{
"url": "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2016/09/07/world/06NYTNow-Obama2/06NYTNow-Obama2-thumbStandard-v2.jpg",
"format": "Standard Thumbnail"
},
{
"url": "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2016/09/07/world/06NYTNow-Obama2/06NYTNow-Obama2-thumbLarge-v2.jpg",
"format": "thumbLarge",
}]
```

another element without the multimedia content:

```
"per_facet": [],
"geo_facet": [],
"multimedia": [],
```

So as you could see, "multimedia" variable on the array has a internal values on one of the element in array and in other it is not.

This is how i try to retrieve that parameter(which is a image).

`<img [src]= "item.multimedia[0].url" *ngIf="item.multimedia[0].url.indexOf('http') === 0">`

When i try to read the url parameter of the multimedia array, 
it results in error ERR:"Cannot read URL of undefined". (Which is completely understandable since there is no data to show.)
This works  for Javascript.  I dono how to solve this.

how to avoid this error and retrieve other parameters from this array successfully.

Thanks in advance.
Suresh

Comment: Please do not post images of code.

Comment: This is not supposed to be `*ngIf`? Also, you know about the `item.multimedia[0].?url` syntax, right?

Comment: "This works for Javascript" How? accessing `([])[0]` is going to give you undefined, which when you use .url is going to cause that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to access the field directly, try checking that it has that item first.

You could do

```
item.multimedia[0] && item.multimedia[0].url.indexOf('http') === 0
```

or

```
item.multimedia.length > 0 && item.multimedia[0].url.indexOf('http') === 0
```

I can't see your whole code so I could be wrong, but typically I'd recommend doing something that doesn't involve individual indexing, which can be very fragile.